# Is there a place to get popular AMIs for Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Amazon has a list of public AMIs:

http://aws.amazon.com/amis

But this list is sorted by date, not popularity, so it's practically useless for finding good AMIs, unless you know in advance what you're looking for. IIUC, There's no way to tell between a super-awesome AMI with thousands of users and a lame AMI that no-one uses.

Is there a popularity-sorted list of AMIs anywhere on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon keeps their usage statistics completely confidential, so there's no such list unfortunately.

Although from my own experience using EC2 it's always good to trust the following kind of images

- Images generated directly by vendors (for example Ubuntu)
- Images generated by VM power houses (Alestic, Rightscale)

This kind of AMIs will guarantee super awesomeness and also super documentation and support

Comment: Thanks, I picked one of the Alestic AMIs and it seems to be good.